# Accessors: Get and Set distinct data types

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, datetime, soap

this is some background to the problem: I'm working with SOAP webservices and I'm getting some issues with the date types. I haven't developed the webservices and for that reason I can't understand them completely. I have a webservice with two methods: `getCountry` and `setCountry`. One of the mandatory fields is the `beginDateField`. The problem is, when I call the `getCountry` method, I get an `error in XML` - just this. I figured it could have something to do with the date fields and to solve the problem, I accessed the `reference.cs` file under the service reference in the solution explorer and changed wherever it had `DateTime` to `string`: and it works perfectly when I want to get the countries from the webservice. What happens is, when I want to call the `setCountry` method, C# asks me for a string but the WebService is expecting a `DateTime`.

Now the specific problem - I've got this bit of code:

```
    private string beginDateField;

    (...)

    public string beginDate {
        get {
            return this.beginDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.beginDateField = value;
        }
    }
```

I need to set the `beginDateField` as a `DateTime` and I have tried this:

```
    set {
        this.beginDateField = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
    }
```

but I get an error:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

(EDIT)

Here's the original error, the one which made me change the `reference.cs` file in the first place.

[image: original error]

The error is in Portuguese and it says `There is an error in the XML document (1, 1274)`

Comment: It seems, that you have to specify the format of the date you're using; see `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how. The format validation should be on the webservice side. From the client side, a `DateTime` should be passed unregarding its specific format (to be validated afterwards by the webservice)

Comment: Breaking the Contract with your Web Services on the client side will lead to nothing. The Web Services wants a DateTime and you can't change that modifying the reference.cs. Why don't you tell us what error you got initially that convinced you to change the reference.cs?

Comment: Hi @Steve, I edited my post and there's the original error: `There is an error in the XML document`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webservices: Error in deserializing body of reply message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990699/webservices-error-in-deserializing-body-of-reply-message)

Comment: @RowlandShaw, I asked that. It's not quite the same. Thanks for your **great** help though...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the format of the string is held in the 'value' inside the beginDate property is not in the correct format due to the System.FormatException you are getting.

More information on FormatException: 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/formatexception

May you post the exact value which is being passed into the set method inside the beginDate property please.

Here is more information on string formats for DateTime:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Hope this helps towards solving your problem. If not please get back to me :)

Comment: No value is being passed, that's an error during coding, I can't even compile it